# How to find and replace number as text?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, find-and-replace

I have a column with the following content:

```
Column
---------
01.6221  
01.6222  
01.6223
```

I need to replace all the "01" with "10", but for some reason when I do the replace, the dot disappears.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Check the formatting of your source. (Difficult for me to be more specific because full stops behave differently with different language settings). If your source is Text it should work.

A workaround might be to replace `01` with `10.` rather than with `10`.